# capitalization of compound proper noun

Tags: grammar

Is "Glasgow area" a compound noun? Can we write "Glasgow Area"?

Glasgow area is in lower case in the Oxford Dictionary in the definition of [*confine*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/confine):

> The work will not be confined to the Glasgow area.

Comment: New York City is a proper name, not a compound noun. I've edited the question to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Glasgow" is the proper noun, the name of the place, so only "Glasgow" is capitalized: "Glasgow area" to refer to the area of and around Glasgow.

OTOH, "New York City" is the name, the proper noun, (to distinguish from the state of the same name), so all three words start with a capital.

HTH.

Comment: so we have some nouns which "city", "street", "lake", etc. are parts of them. You mean we call them by those , in this case we should consider them as proper.

Comment: Fountain street is true, and if it was a part of its name we should write Fountain Street?

Comment: Yes. "Fleet Street," "Bantam Lake."